# Extracting binary data from string with sign bit set in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string that looks like this "��is some test text"

The first 2 bytes are the length of the rest of the string (this is legacy network traffic that cannot be changed).

It decodes ok when the sign bit isn't set in the binary data but if it is I get rubbish.

Here is a little test program:

```
var decode = '';

//decode = new Buffer('ffff', 'hex');
//decode = new Buffer('85ff', 'hex');
decode = new Buffer('364e', 'hex');
//decode = new Buffer('7f5a', 'hex');
//decode = new Buffer('00ff', 'hex');

decode += '<this>is some test text</this>';
console.log(decode);

var testbuf = decode.slice(0,2);
console.log('testbuf =' + testbuf);

var myLength1 = decode.slice(0,1).charCodeAt('hex').toString(16);
console.log('ml1 ' + myLength1.toString());

var myLength2 = decode.slice(1,2).charCodeAt('hex').toString(16);
console.log('ml2 ' + myLength2.toString());

var myLength = myLength1 + myLength2;
console.log('mylength =' + myLength1 + myLength2);

 var foo2 = parseInt(myLength, 16);
 console.log('ml3 ' + foo2.toString());
```

Using the code above the output looks like this;

```
 node foo.js
 6N<this>is some test text</this>
 testbuf =6N
 ml1 36
 ml2 4e
 mylength =364e
 ml3 13902
```

The answer is correct when the sign bit isn't set, but if the data contains a value with the high bit set, I end up with fffd for each character with the high order bit set (the replacement character).

This is output with high order bit data (using the 0x85ff data line above):

```
 node foo.js
 ��<this>is some test text</this>
 testbuf =��
 ml1 fffd
 ml2 fffd
 mylength =fffdfffd
 ml3 4294836221
```

I know it's because the charCodeAt() function desires to return 'fffd' as the replacement character for what it sees as non ascii, the question is, what is the alternative for extracting binary data from a string?

Thanks